# How do I use the CSS transition property correctly in this code snippet?

Tags: css, angular

I want my main content to transition at 500ms to the right as the Navigational Sidebar transits to the right on the click of a hamburger icon on the header. The navigation is working fine and transits linearly at 500ms. In the respective template files of both components I added an active class with the property, transition: all 500ms linear; The Navigation Sidebar works fine but the main content shifts to right abruptly, i.e. transition is not working correctly and I can't figure out what is wrong in the css. Link to the source code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qycauv

P.S. I am new to Web Development, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the content to be pushed to the right or you want the sidebar to be over the content?

Comment: I want the content to be pushed to the right(which it does, but the transition does not work) and I want content to be responsive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lists element does not transition because it doesn't know where to transition from. You should first set the left property to 0px, before transitioning it to 200px. Like so...

```
#lists.active {
    left: 200px;
}

#lists {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    transition: all 500ms linear;
}
```

Comment: this worked! please help me understand though, if we do not mention left:0px, shouldn't transition(by default) from the original element location?

Comment: You would assume that, but that is not the case (sadly).

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `transition: all 500ms linear;` to the `.container` class and not on `.active` class

Comment: Hello, use `transform: translateX(200px)` instead of `left: 200px`. It should work, then add `transform: translateX(0)` to the `.container` class and put the `transition: all 500ms linear;` to the `.container`

Comment: the problem was that list elements did not know where to transition from, so I had to mention left:0px inside of #list{} and that did the trick, thanks mate